# C# netcore3.1 Linq: is it advisable to use Select() to call "impure" functions?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, functional-programming

Given an "impure" (i.e., side-effect-producing) function such as this:

```
public MyResultClass DoWork(MyEntityClass myEntity)
{
    if (myEntity.DateUpdated == default)
        myEntity.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    MyResultClass result = _dbUtility.InsertOrUpdate(myEntity);
    return result;          
}
```

AFAIK, this would not be a pure function since it has side effects - i.e. it modifies the input object (using a non-deterministic value, no less!) and performs an insert/update operation on a database.

However, with `Linq` - which is (arguably) regarded as a purely functional subset of C# - the following is legal, and works as would be expected from a "non-pure-functional" context:

```
IEnumerable<MyResultClass> = myIEnumerableEntities.Select(entity => DoWork(entity));
```

Meaning that (1) `myObject`'s `DateUpdated` property is modified (if `default`) and (2), the database insert/update happens successfully.

Does this indicate that `Linq` is not truly a functional sublanguage?  Or am I misunderstanding the concepts of pure functions and functional programming?  (At any rate, I still plan to use this pattern unless there are best-practice reasons for me to avoid it; and if there are such reasons not to, I will certainly consider those).

Comment: Add `ToList()` at the end of the query. But REMEMBER, standard LINQ for querying data, not modification. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: Thanks @svyatoslav-danyliv - I think `foreach` makes the most sense.  I would prefer that over `ToList()` since that materializes the entire dataset instead of lazy-loading each record, which could cause performance/memory issues.

Comment: LINQ is *intended* to be used in a functional manner, but there is nothing in the semantics that mandates it. C# remains an imperative language at its core and there is nothing to express that a method or delegate is free of side effects. The reasons you should want to avoid side effects is that they make the proper functioning of code much harder to reason about, potentially break things if what you're modifying is what's being queried in the first place, inhibit parallelism (which is a shame, since PLINQ happens to be very convenient) and subvert the expectations of the reader in queries.

Answer (score 1):

[C# makes no explicit distinction](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/24/discerning-and-maintaining-purity) between [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and impure actions. Thus, with [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) such as `Select` or `SelectMany`, you can pass impure actions as arguments. Nothing in the language prevents that. LINQ cannot, for that reason, be considered a strictly functional subset of C#.

What is true is that C# query syntax is based on the concept of [functors](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors) and [monads](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads), which were first popularised in the strictly functional language [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org). Haskell also famously uses a particular monad called [IO](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/06/08/the-io-container) to model impure actions, so in that case you could argue that performing side-effects inside of a `SelectMany` (monadic *bind*) call would be, in some sense, idiomatic. [The monad to use, however, ought to be the asynchronous monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/07/27/task-asynchronous-programming-as-an-io-surrogate) rather than [the List monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/04/19/the-list-monad).

It's [not considered idiomatic to perform side effects inside of `IEnumerable<T>.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach). Use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score -2):

> Add ToList() at the end of the query. But REMEMBER, standard LINQ for
> querying data, not modification. Use foreach instead. –  Svyatoslav
> Danyliv
>
> LINQ is intended to be used in a functional manner, but there is
> nothing in the semantics that mandates it. C# remains an imperative
> language at its core and there is nothing to express that a method or
> delegate is free of side effects. The reasons you should want to avoid
> side effects is that they make the proper functioning of code much
> harder to reason about, potentially break things if what you're
> modifying is what's being queried in the first place, inhibit
> parallelism (which is a shame, since PLINQ happens to be very
> convenient) and subvert the expectations of the reader in queries. –
> Jeroen Mostert

@svyatoslav-danyliv and @jeroen-mostert have answered my question.  Thanks!

Comment: You should not post answers copying other people's comments. If someone answered your question in a comment, politely ask them in they want to post their comment as an answer, then mark their answer as the correct answer to give proper credit. What you are doing here could be seen as an exploitation of the system to give you free points.

Comment: @julealgon: While it’s certainly better etiquette to give author’s in the comments the opportunity to promote their comments to answers, it’s perfectly acceptable to do so on their behalf so long as the source is correctly attributed. That said, as another point of etiquette, I normally do so as a Community Wiki since it’s not my original work.